# Maintaining consistent spacing with autoresizing masks for three text fields

Tags: ios, storyboard, autoresizingmask

On my iPad storyboard, I have 3 text fields with a consistent spacing in portrait mode.  I assigned autoresizing masks as shown in the image below, but after rotation to landscape, there is a gap between the second and third text fields.

If I want to maintain the left and right margins after rotation (currently on the first and third text field masks), is there a way to specify that these three text fields should be resized in the same manner?

The storyboard does not currently have auto layout or size classes enabled.

[image: rotation]

Comment: In landscape mode, are the widths of all three text boxes the same? It's hard to tell from your diagram.

Comment: @GlennRay In portrait mode, all text fields are 180 pixels wide.  After rotation to landscape mode, the left two fields are 248 pixels, but the rightmost one is 264 pixels wide.

Comment: With Auto Layout, this would be so easy.  You just select all three text fields and give them a constraint of equal widths. The only solution I see without Auto Layout is to change the physical width of all three text fields to one value for portrait and to another value in landscape, making the change in a function that detects a change in device orientation.